# What is the best way to use python to serve web pages in IIS 6.0

Tags: python, iis, wsgi, isapi

I have an IIS 6.0 web server that I currently use to serve some vanilla ASP pages, and I'm finding ASP somewhat limited. I use python quite a bit for automation tasks, and various other things, and would like to begin using it with IIS to serve web pages.

My question is this: What is the best way to do this? I define best as easiest, fastest, and most well documented. I would like to avoid CGI/FastCGI, as I am told that they are less preferable due to having to start the python interpreter every time a page is requested. (Correct me if I am wrong)

I've read about ISAPI and WSGI, and various flavors and combinations thereof, and am fairly confused about the whole thing. I would like to use the latest technology, but every tutorial I have found on this is very cryptic. A good tutorial on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Using Python Scripts with IIS"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494)

Comment: I have read and tried this already, and several other pages out there that do the same thing, all I get is "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error" when executing the test code. Can you give any insight on how to diagnose this? I have send verbose error messages to client turned on in IIS.

Comment: I should Add, I am using ActivePython 2.7.02

Comment: Which mechanism are you using, CGI or ASP?

Comment: TBH, I've never really run IIS. You could try running `win32com\AXScript\Client\pyscript.py` to reregister Python as a scripting provider though.

Comment: Tried that too, It seems to succeed, but I get the same error. Oddly, the file is actually located here: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\axscript\client but none of the tutorials mention that, I guess the location changed or something.

Comment: @Patrick:  "all I get is "HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error" when executing the test code."  Then ask **that** question.  Provide details.  Provide the error message.  Provide the logs.  Focus on the actual problem you're actually having.  A 500 server error means your IIS doesn't have mod_wsgi or your mod_wsgi config is wrong or your Python code is broken.  Provide details and we can help with that.